# add data to root hash with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'd like to add request info to response from RABL

my code looks like

```
object @collection => :response
attributes :id, :submitted_at, :address, :name, :data
rest_of_code_omitted
```

I've tried to add

```
node(:request, :object_root =>true ) do
   {request: {
       url: request.original_url,
       status: 200,
       errors: {
       } }}
 end
```

but this code adds request node to each object from collection, while i want this node to be rendered once above collection node.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
object false
node :request do
  {
    request: {
      url: request.original_url,
      status: 200,
      errors: { }
    }
  }
end

child(@collection => :response) do
  attributes :id, :submitted_at, :address, :name, :data
end
```

This should do the trick. `object false` directive is what puts the node at the root level.